# Copy elision and exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, copy-constructor

After reading about copy elision of [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) I wanted to play with exceptions and copy elision. 
So I wrote the following code with gcc 7.2 on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc566db0e757b85e)

```
#include <iostream>

class Exception
{
public:
    Exception() { std::cout << "constructed\n"; }
    Exception(Exception& other) {std::cout << "copy constructed\n";}
    Exception(const Exception& other) {std::cout << "copy constructed\n";}
    Exception(Exception&& other) {std::cout << "move constructed\n";}
};

void foo()
{
    throw Exception();
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        foo();
    }
    catch(Exception e )
    {

    }
}
```

Output

> constructed
>   copy constructed

We can see that the copy constructor is called and this happens even when gcc is invoked with -O2. 
It seems to me that this code should be eligible to copy elision according to the following clause :

> When handling an exception, if the argument of the catch clause is of
>   the same type (ignoring top-level cv-qualification) as the exception
>   object thrown, the copy is omitted and the body of the catch clause
>   accesses the exception object directly, as if caught by reference.

So why is the copy constructor called? Why does copy elision not work in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cppreference is inaccurate on this. There is in fact no guarantee that the copy will be elided except in a *constant expression* (`constexpr`) or a *constant initialization* (static or thread-local). That is not the case in your example.

See [[class.copy.elision]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#1) in the current C++17 draft (emphasis mine):

> When certain criteria are met, ... elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision, is ***permitted*** in the following circumstances:
>
> — in a *throw-expression*, when the operand is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) whose scope does not extend beyond the end of the innermost enclosing try-block (if there is one), the copy/move operation from the operand to the exception object can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the exception object
>
> Copy elision is ***required*** where an expression is evaluated in a context requiring a *constant expression* and in *constant initialization*.

That means that some day it may be implemented as a compiler optimization, it is just not the case currently.

It would be wise therefore to `catch` by `const&` for the time being (also to avoid accidental slicing).

Answer (score 0):

Just, the elision your compiler did not perform for you when catching the exception is non-mandatory. It is only permitted but not obligated to perform the elision.

Note, the elision your compiler did perform for you when throwing is non-mandatory too.

And it is how it is described in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision at present.

Of course, you can avoid this calling of the copy constructor, catch the exception by reference,
either

```
catch (const Exception & e)
```

or

```
catch (Exception & e)
```

(according to your needs).